# How to replace blank space with new line? in notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of some data which is in this format for example

word1 word2 word3

word4 word5

word6 word7 word8 word9

but I want to split it all up so that each word is in new line so it would become like:

word1

word2

word3

word4

word5

word6

word7

word8

word9

the blank space between the words is perfect seperator which could be used in search&replace but Not sure of what would the code be in notepad++ regex search?

Thanks

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rG2yV3/1

Answer (score 25):

Entering `\s+` on the **`Find what`** field and `\n` (Change to `\n\n` for two new lines) on the **`Replace With`** field followed by **`Replace All`** transforms:

```
word1 word2 word3

word4 word5

word6 word7 word8 word9
```

onto:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
word7
word8
word9
```

Comment: `( |\s+)` is redundant. Just use `\s+`.

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly :) thanks a lot for real! really helped me out.

Comment: Thing to note here, in the 'search mode' at the bottom, select 'Regular Expression'